# How to Related BizTalk Health/Performance Monitor Instance Names

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

How does one correlate the instance names on the "Performance counters" in BizTalk Health Monitor to the actual instance names.

[image]

I checked the Id numbers in BizTalkMgmtDB like this, but I have 25 of those (or 24 if you don't count the Isolated Host Instance).  The numbers in the performance monitor go from BTSNTSVC#1 to BTSNTSVC#20, and one of them is just BTSNTSVC with no number after it.   (Maybe the only have enough slots to add the first 20?)

[image]

I also checked

```
SELECT * FROM [BizTalkMsgBoxDb].[dbo].[Instances]
```

Sandro has a PowerShell that matches ProcessId to HostInstances, but ProcessIds are much bigger numbers.

Comment: I would use the PAL tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/using-the-performance-analysis-of-logs-pal-tool

Comment: @Dijkgraaf So the idea is to run PerfMon, capture to a .csv, then analyze it with PAL?  It wants me to point it to a "performance counter log", and it also says I need "Microsoft Log Parser".  Do I have to install that and run it first?